# How to keep/add CDATA section with XSLT on specified subnodes?

Tags: xml, xslt

I have an XML File with the following structure:

```
<catalog>
    <category>
        <display-name>    XYZ       </display-name> 
    </category>
    <product>
        <display-name>    ABC       </display-name>
    </product>
</catalog>
```

How can I add CDATA section on all subnodes catalog/product/display-name ?

This is the kind of code I wrote , how can I chosse the specified subnodes on cdata-section-elements :

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="no" indent="yes" cdata-section-elements="?"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
 <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
  <xsl:copy>
   <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
  </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>
 <xsl:template match="catalog">
  <catalog catalog-id="master-catalog">
   <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
  </catalog>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Thanks for help !

Comment: Well, you can use `cdata-section-elements="display-name"` to have any text content of that element serialized as a CDATA section. You can't make it depend on the parent or ancestor element, it would do that for any `display-name` element in the output.

Answer (score 0):

As I said in a comment, the standard way since XSLT 1 is to list `cdata-section-elements="display-name"`, although that will apply to any `display-name` elements in the result.

In XSLT 3, if you want to serialize an element as a CDATA section based on its match pattern, you could use the serialize function on it and then the `disable-output-escaping` hack:

```
  <xsl:template match="category/display-name | product/display-name">
      <xsl:value-of select="serialize(., map { 'cdata-section-elements' : node-name() })"
                    disable-output-escaping="yes"/>
  </xsl:template>
```